# Texture Atlas manipulate uv's from one mesh each

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I'm trying to combine uv maps of multiple objects into one texture coordinate so I can have only one texture map when baking. For this purpose, I'm using the Texture Atlas Addon. I select my objects and clicked "StartManualUnwrap" button, and I see the screen below.

[image]

Here, I want to the uv map of each mesh and manipulate it (scale and translate). However, I don't know how I can select the mesh of only one object in this mode. For example, in the picture above, I want to make only one mesh orange. All selected objects seem to be combined in this mode, so I can't manipulate them separately.

How do I select vertices of the same mesh for manipulation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really clear what is the purpose of the Texture Atlas here then.. Temporarily joining objects into one is what Texture Atlas does to allow you select multiple meshes and unwrap them simultaneously. If you ask how to select linked geometry of one mesh then use Ctrl+L with at least one vertex of the desired mesh selected.

Comment: Thank you Mr Zak, yes selecting the linked geometry of one mesh is what I want to do to manipulate them separately. How do I select one vertex though? It seems like I can only select an edge on uv space.

Comment: Selection depends on the [selection mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html#selection-mode), press Ctrl+Tab to enable the desired one. Selecting linked will work with any of them so with an edge selected as well. Note that this should be done in 3d viewport